# Regex (Do not include digit.digit)

Tags: regex

This is a sample text i'm running my regex on:

```
DuraFlexHose Water 1/2" hex    300mm 30.00
```

I want to include everything and stop at the `30.00`

So what I have in mind is something like `[^\d*\.\d*]*` but that's not working. What is the query that would help me acheive this?

Comment: You can use `^(.+?)\b\d+\.\d+` and use captured group #1

Comment: Thanks @anubhava that works, but I'm trying to go through it to understand it.

Comment: Can't you split the string by space (or tab) and concatenate back all but the last elements? What is the language you are using? With a look-ahead, the result will be "cleaner": [`^.*?(?=\s*\d+\.\d+$)`](https://regex101.com/r/mD3bS1/2). Or is it CSV? Then use a CSV reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mO0vV1/2)

```
/.*(?=\d{2}\.\d{2})/
    .* matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    (?=\d{2}\.\d{2}) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
        \d{2} match a digit [0-9]
            Quantifier: {2} Exactly 2 times
        \. matches the character . literally
        \d{2} match a digit [0-9]
            Quantifier: {2} Exactly 2 times
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use any CSV parser and are only limited to regex, I'd suggest 2 regexps.

This one can be used to grab every character from the beginning up to the first pattern of `optional spaces` + `digits(s)` + `.` + `digit(s)`:

```
^([\s\S]*?)\s*\d+\.\d+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iG3kJ2/1)

In case the float value is at the end of string, use a `$` anchor (the end of string):

```
^([\s\S]*?)\s*\d+\.\d+$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/iG3kJ2/2)

Note that `[\s\S]` matches any symbol, even a newline.

Regex breakdown:

- `^` - Start of string
- `([\s\S]*?)` - (Capture group 1) any symbols, 0 or more, as few as possible otherwise, `3` from `30.45` will be captured)
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace, as many as possible (so as to trim Group 1)
- `\d+\.\d+` - 1 or more digits followed by a period followed by 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

If you plan to match any floats, like `-.05`, you will need to replace `\d+\.\d+` with `[+-]?\d*\.?\d+`.

Here is how it can be used:

```js
var str = 'DuraFlexHose Water 1/2" hex    300mm 300.00';
var res = str.match(/^([\s\S]*?)\s*\d+\.\d+/); 
if (res !== null) {
    document.write(res[1]);
}
```

Comment: FYI: Using the currently selected solution, [the result will not be what you expect](https://regex101.com/r/vS9sU1/1) if your input can have more than 2-digit integer part (e.g. `DuraFlexHose Water 1/2" hex    300mm 300.00`).